# Custom Serialization of Inherited List

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, xml-serialization

If I have a base class that inherits from a generic list, and the derived class needs to be serialized with a custom name for the list entries how can I enter the correct serializartion attributes and/or refer to the base list?

```
Public MustInherit Class SpecialList(Of T)
   Inherits List(Of T)
   'Other methods here
End Class

Public Class Cache
   Inherits SpecialList(Of CacheEntry)

   <XmlElementAttribute("CustomName")> _
   Public Property Entries() As List(Of CacheEntry)
      Get
         Return ???
      End Get
      Set(value As List(Of CacheEntry))
         ??? = value
      End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

Is this actually possible without either overriding the base class methods, writing custom serialization, or implementing IXmlSerializable?

I'm expecting to get output XML something like this:

```
<cache>
    <customname></customname>
    <customname></customname>
</cache>
```

Comment: Yes, see the code above, it doesn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an [`XmlRootAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) to `CacheEntry`:

```
<XmlRootAttribute(ElementName:="customname")>
Public Class CacheEntry
```

As a side question, if `Cache` inherits from `List` (through `SpecialList`) then why do you have a `Entries` property that's also a `List`?